# How to test my destroy action with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

In my Rails app, if a `user` wants to delete his own account he will first have to enter his password in my `terminate` view:

```
<%= form_for @user, :method => :delete do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :password %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

This is my `UsersController`:

```
def terminate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Terminate your account"
end

def destroy
  if @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account was terminated."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Wrong password."
    render :terminate
  end
end
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to test this with RSpec.

What I have is this:

```
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do

  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  context "success" do

    it "deletes the user" do
      expect{ 
        delete :destroy, :id => @user, :password => "password"
      }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

  end

end
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
Missing template users/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
* "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007fa7f51310d8>"
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here or suggest a better way to test this action?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can this destroy action be tested with RSpec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810635/how-can-this-destroy-action-be-tested-with-rspec)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rspec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/controller-specs/views-are-stubbed-by-default) `Views are stubbed by default`. So, I think you should add `controller.prepend_view_path 'users/destroy'` in test method.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps, add `controller.prepend_view_path 'app/views'`, it's not clear from docs.

Answer (score 0):

First wrong what I sow is:

In destroy action you have `params[:user][:password]` but in test you give only `params[:id]` and `params[:password]`

in controller you create `@user` in `before_filter`?